# download images in python with Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

I want to download a photo from the Iranian website and put the code in the culab and get timeout error and URLerror.

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import urllib.request
    
    def make_soup(url):
      thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
      #req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
      #thepage = urlopen(req).read()
      soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
      return soupdata
    
    i=1
    soup = make_soup("https://www.banikhodro.com/car/pride/")
    for img in soup.find_all('img'):
      temp = img.get('src')
      #print(temp)
      if temp[0]=="/":
          image = "https://www.banikhodro.com/car/pride/"+temp
      else:
          image = temp
      #print(image)    
      nametemp = img.get('alt')
      nametemp = str(nametemp)
      if len(nametemp)== 0:
          i=i+1
      else:
          filename=nametemp
          
      imagefile = open(filename+ ".jpeg", 'wb')
      imagefile.write(urllib.request.urlopen(image).read())
      imagefile.close()
```

```
TimeoutError                              Traceback (most recent call last)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py in _new_conn(self)
    158             conn = connection.create_connection(
--> 159                 (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
    160 

15 frames

TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NewConnectionError                        Traceback (most recent call last)

NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f079e4cdcf8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

MaxRetryError                             Traceback (most recent call last)

MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.banikhodro.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /car/pride/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f079e4cdcf8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out',))


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ConnectionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    514                 raise SSLError(e, request=request)
    515 
--> 516             raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
    517 
    518         except ClosedPoolError as e:

ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.banikhodro.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /car/pride/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f079e4cdcf8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out',))
```

add timeout error and connection error.These errors are given to me in GoogelColab when use Iranian Websait for downloded images in colab
Thanks in advance to those who answer my questions

Comment: Could you please include the complete error in your question itself. It will help us understand your problem better.

Comment: Yes, Sure. I edit code and I add the error to the code

Comment: Thank you for your answer and my problem was solved in Spider, but I still have a high error in colab.
Another question is how to download the photos of the next pages (ie all the photos on different pages should be downloaded in one place)

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this would be:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://www.banikhodro.com/car/pride/").content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html5lib").find_all("span", {"class": "photo"})
images = [
    f"https://www.banikhodro.com{img.find('img')['src']}" for img in soup
    if "Adv" in img.find("img")["src"]
]
for image in images:
    print(f"Fetching {image}")
    with open(image.rsplit("/")[-1], "wb") as img:
        img.write(requests.get(image).content)
```

This fetches all non-generic images of car offers to your local folder.

```
183093_1-m.jpg
183098_1-m.jpg
183194_1-m.jpg
183208_1-m.jpg
183209_1-m.jpg
183272_1-m.jpg
183279_1-m.jpg
183286_1-m.jpg
183384_1-m.jpg
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. My problem was solved in Spider and the photos were arranged, but I still have an error in the colab.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and my problem was solved in Spider, but I still have a high error in colab.
Another question is how to download the photos of the next pages (ie all the photos on different pages should be downloaded in one place)

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://www.banikhodro.com/car/pride/").content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html5lib")
images = [
    f"https://www.banikhodro.com{img['src']}" for img in soup.find_all('img')
    # sort it accordingly based on class or id inside find_all method
]
for image in images:
    print(f"Fetching {image}")
    with open(image.split("/")[-1], "wb") as img:
        img.write(requests.get(image).content)
```

1. pip install requests # to install the most preferred requests module
2. This code will give all kinds of images including footer etc.
3. You can sort those image data in find_all method which has an parameter called attrs
   for more info refer : [click here](https://www.kite.com/python/docs/bs4.BeautifulSoup.find_all)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, my problem was solved in Spider, but I still have an error in colab

Comment: Another question is how to download the photos of the next pages (ie all the photos on different pages should be downloaded in one place)

Comment: For that, you need to iterate over all 'a' tags in the first link and store those links either in a list or file then iterate it over one by one link and do the above one in each iteration to get and store images. But it seems like web scraping and it's endless.
Refer this: https://github.com/jjnanthakumar/website-crawler/blob/master/link_finder.py